# Python, Django rest framework, create a field that contains a choices or free text

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django rest framework API.

I'm looking to add to it a field, which contains either choices or free text.

I want that if the user decided to add a new value to the field, it will be added to the DB.

The

I have an the following exsiting model:

```py
class Points(models.Model):
    mission_name = models.CharField(name='MissionName',
                                    verbose_name="Mission Name",
                                    unique=True,
                                    max_length=255,
                                    blank=False,
                                    help_text="Enter the mission's name"
                                    )

        location_name = models.CharField(choices= # fetch known locations from the DB 
                                                  #or create a new one) 
                                     # Show existing options or input a new one.
                                     # If an existing location has been chosen then it's Latitude and Longitude are of the fetched object.
                                     # Pretty sure that this kind of action belongs in the serializer or the view.



    latitude = models.FloatField(name="GDT1Latitude",
                                 verbose_name="GDT 1 Latitude",
                                 unique=False, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                 help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                 default=DEFAULT_VALUE)
    longitude = models.FloatField(name="GDT1Longitude",
                                  verbose_name="GDT 1 Longitude",
                                  unique=False, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                  help_text="Enter the location's Longitude, second when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                  default=DEFAULT_VALUE)

    area = models.CharField(
        name='Area',
        max_length=8,
        choices=AREAS,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make another model Location, and put foreign key in your point model:

```
enter code here
class Points(models.Model): 
location_name = models.ForeignKey(Location,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=true)


class Location(models.Model):
#any info you want to store
```